# Solve "Something went wrong" error remotely

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gdm, segmentation-fault

There are several similar questions about the annoying and useless "Oh no. Something went wrong" error message, but:

1. no solutions worked for me (see below)
2. I don't have a physical access to the machine, only SSH connection (or remote desktop when Gnome is working...)

The machine runs Ubuntu 22.04 and the error appears at the login.
I tried:

```
$ mv ~/.config ~/.config-backup && reboot
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I'm pretty sure this is caused by gnome, because:

```
$ ls /var/crash
_usr_bin_gnome-shell.123.crash

$ sudo dmesg | grep error
[    9.426568] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
[    9.547525] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
[    9.621761] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
[    9.693187] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
[   22.831223] gnome-shell[1100]: segfault at 25e9b00b8 ip 00007f102937308d sp 00007ffd248632d0 error 4 in libxkbcommon-x11.so.0.0.0[7f1029372000+4000]
[   23.302667] gnome-shell[1106]: segfault at 2060300b8 ip 00007f185f9ca08d sp 00007ffcfb152710 error 4 in libxkbcommon-x11.so.0.0.0[7f185f9c9000+4000]

$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep error
Oct  6 07:18:33 mark kernel: [8112176.475263] audit: type=1400 audit(1665033513.397:37): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" info="profile does not exist" error=-2 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mariadbd" pid=377011 comm="apparmor_parser"
Oct  6 07:18:37 mark mariadbd[377159]: 2022-10-06  7:18:37 0 [ERROR] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
Oct  6 07:18:37 mark /etc/mysql/debian-start[377180]: Reading datadir from the MariaDB server failed. Got the following error when executing the 'mysql' command line client
Oct  6 07:34:16 mark pipewire[401657]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Oct  6 07:34:16 mark pipewire-media-session[401658]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Oct  6 07:34:16 mark pipewire[401657]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Oct  6 07:39:02 mark cloud-init[689]: 2022-10-06 05:39:01,384 - schema.py[WARNING]: Invalid cloud-config provided: Please run 'sudo cloud-init schema --system' to see the schema errors.
Oct  6 07:39:02 mark systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch) being skipped.
Oct  6 07:39:02 mark systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (timer based) being skipped.
Oct  6 07:39:02 mark kernel: [    8.558820] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
Oct  6 07:39:02 mark kernel: [    8.632859] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
Oct  6 07:39:02 mark kernel: [    8.718295] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
Oct  6 07:39:02 mark kernel: [    8.761076] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
Oct  6 07:39:02 mark mariadbd[858]: 2022-10-06  7:39:02 0 [ERROR] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
Oct  6 07:39:03 mark /etc/mysql/debian-start[916]: Reading datadir from the MariaDB server failed. Got the following error when executing the 'mysql' command line client
Oct  6 07:39:09 mark /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1076]: #011(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
Oct  6 07:39:11 mark gnome-session[1116]: gnome-session-binary[1116]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Oct  6 07:39:11 mark gnome-session[1116]: gnome-session-binary[1116]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Oct  6 07:39:11 mark gnome-session-binary[1116]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Oct  6 07:39:11 mark gnome-session-binary[1116]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Oct  6 07:39:11 mark kernel: [   21.908467] gnome-shell[1143]: segfault at 1af300b8 ip 00007f4dac02808d sp 00007ffd0b52b7c0 error 4 in libxkbcommon-x11.so.0.0.0[7f4dac027000+4000]
Oct  6 07:39:13 mark kernel: [   23.199881] gnome-shell[1160]: segfault at a180b8 ip 00007fbe2a2c208d sp 00007ffd9b11f090 error 4 in libxkbcommon-x11.so.0.0.0[7fbe2a2c1000+4000]
Oct  6 07:45:49 mark pipewire[1651]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Oct  6 07:45:49 mark pipewire-media-session[1652]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Oct  6 07:45:49 mark pipewire[1651]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Oct  6 07:51:29 mark cloud-init[692]: 2022-10-06 05:51:28,589 - schema.py[WARNING]: Invalid cloud-config provided: Please run 'sudo cloud-init schema --system' to see the schema errors.
Oct  6 07:51:29 mark systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch) being skipped.
Oct  6 07:51:29 mark systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (timer based) being skipped.
Oct  6 07:51:29 mark kernel: [    9.426568] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
Oct  6 07:51:29 mark kernel: [    9.547525] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
Oct  6 07:51:29 mark kernel: [    9.621761] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
Oct  6 07:51:29 mark kernel: [    9.693187] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
Oct  6 07:51:30 mark mariadbd[848]: 2022-10-06  7:51:30 0 [ERROR] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
Oct  6 07:51:30 mark /etc/mysql/debian-start[878]: Reading datadir from the MariaDB server failed. Got the following error when executing the 'mysql' command line client
Oct  6 07:51:36 mark /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1038]: #011(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
Oct  6 07:51:38 mark gnome-session[1070]: gnome-session-binary[1070]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Oct  6 07:51:38 mark gnome-session[1070]: gnome-session-binary[1070]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Oct  6 07:51:38 mark gnome-session-binary[1070]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Oct  6 07:51:38 mark gnome-session-binary[1070]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Oct  6 07:51:38 mark kernel: [   22.831223] gnome-shell[1100]: segfault at 25e9b00b8 ip 00007f102937308d sp 00007ffd248632d0 error 4 in libxkbcommon-x11.so.0.0.0[7f1029372000+4000]
Oct  6 07:51:39 mark kernel: [   23.302667] gnome-shell[1106]: segfault at 2060300b8 ip 00007f185f9ca08d sp 00007ffcfb152710 error 4 in libxkbcommon-x11.so.0.0.0[7f185f9c9000+4000]
Oct  6 07:53:13 mark pipewire[1352]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Oct  6 07:53:13 mark pipewire-media-session[1353]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Oct  6 07:53:13 mark pipewire[1352]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
```

What should I need to do in order to fix this error?

Comment: A segfault is an error with memory-handling caused by a mistake in the library's source code. It's a bug. Please file a bug report clearly detailing the minimum number of steps to reliably reproduce the bug in a pre-release (22.10) LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. Bugs that cannot be reproduced generally cannot be fixed.

Comment: As a workaround, try a different workflow: Try different applications, or try starting your current applications in a different order.

Comment: @user535733 it happens before the login screen, in which sense I have to starts my applications in different order?

Comment: Why my question "does not meet the guidelines"?

Comment: Since I have no access to that machine I cannot try using a LiveUSB environment. I have to fix it remotely.

Comment: @user535733 sorry, perhaps it was not clear enough. I have a **working** SSH connection and a remote desktop software that allows me to understand if Gnome is working again.

Comment: Since you have ssh, backup your data since the machine seems unreliable. Try reinstalling the `libxkbcommon-x11-0` package on the broken machine. If that doesn't fix it, then you might need to reinstall Ubuntu (very difficult remotely). You use a LiveUSB to reproduce the bug on a local machine or environment so you can report it-- you don't need to reproduce it on your broken machine; the developer working the bug won't have access to your hardware.

Comment: @user535733 I'm going to try to reinstall `libxkbcommon-x11-0`, but if it were a bug there should be tons of user with this problem. I'm afraid it's something related to some wrong configuration.

Comment: There are a few bug reports out there for `libxkbcommon-x11-0` but they are uncommon. Nevertheless, that's what your error messages claimed was the fault that crashed gnome-shell. Might be a corrupted lib (hence the reinstall), might be some wrong config (that would also be a bug -- should cause an error message but not crash!), might be an incompatibility with your remote-desktop server, might be lots of possibilities.

Comment: @user535733 just reinstalled. Nothing has changed. I don't think it's a problem with the remote desktop (I tried Anydesk and Zoho Assist) and before updating to 22.04 all worked fine.